# C: Sizeof of 2D-array - difference between pointer and first element

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, sizeof

I have an array similar to the following 2D array in C:

```
uint16_t myArray[2][14] = {
                    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14},
                    { 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114} 
                };
```

I wanted to get the size of the array and used:

```
printf("size: %d \n", sizeof(myArray) / sizeof( * myArray));
```

with the result

```
size: 2
```

When I used the first element of the first subarray

```
printf("size: %d \n", sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0][0]));
```

... I got the correct result:

```
size: 28
```

Is this because I initialized my array with 2 subarrays or is there another explanation?

Comment: `*myArray` is equivalent to `myArray[0]`. In one case you're dividing 2x14=28 elements by 14 elements, in the second you're dividing 28 element by 1 element. The initialization has nothing to do with it, it's about the type `uint16_t [2][14]`.

Comment: Both results are correct — but they are different answers to different questions.

Comment: [refer](https://onlinegdb.com/mOqN-G9MN)

Comment: @ThomasJager Thanks, makes sense. So instead of `myArray[0][0]` I could have used a pointer to this element?

Comment: @sebo1234 You could take a pointer to it, and take the `sizeof` the dereferencing of that, though it's a lot more clear with the array syntax.

Comment: @all Thanks for your answers and explanations.

Comment: This isn't valid C so your main concern here is how you managed to get this to compile. `008` is nonsense for example and you most likely didn't want octal base numbers.

Comment: @Lundin You're right. I mistakenly copied an incorrect version of the array. Edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the length of the array using this:

```c
printf("size: %d \n", sizeof(myArray) / sizeof( * myArray));
```

You are getting the size of the array and then dividing it by the size of the first element, which is in turn another array. Because there is another array inside it with a length described in the variable declaration, it will get the size of the array rather than a `*uint16_t`. In effect, you are getting the amount of memory allocated by the whole array, and then dividing it by the size of the amount of memory allocated by the array inside, which as there are only two elements is 2.

`Whole 2D array (28 * sizeof(uint16_t)): 001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007, 008, 009, 010, 011, 012, 013, 014, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114`

`1D array inside 2D (14 * sizeof(uint16_t)): 001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007, 008, 009, 010, 011, 012, 013, 014`

When using the size of the element inside, you are dividing `28 * sizeof(uint16_t)` by `14 * sizeof(uint16_t)`, which is 2. However, when using the size of the element inside, you are dividing `28 * sizeof(uint16_t)` by `sizeof(uint16_t)`, which is 28.

Hope this makes sense :)